# Use variable values as the value for a macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have one SAS dataset that has a column with values that I want to use as a macro variable. Say the SAS dataset looks like this with one column:

```
varname
34
367
399
87
```

What I want is for all of the values in the column to become a concatenated string in a macro variable (suitable for using in an `if` statement with the `in` operator). The result would be equivalent to this:

`%let var = %str('34','367','399','87');`

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `PROC SQL`, but there are other ways:

```
proc sql noprint;
select "'" || varname || "'"
   into :var separated by ','
   from have;
quit;

%put var: &var;
```

This will concatenate the variable values with a `'` on either side.  The `separated by` piece will put a `,` between all the values.  `:var` tells SQL to save the results in a macro named `var`;